# CumulusCI: Error: Could not process MDAPI response, but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: cumulusci

I have set up this structure of metadata to be deployed as a pre step, before I can push the main code. Please note that this package is dependent on another package, which is already deployed.

[image]

And this is the content of package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>hed__Affiliation__c.Annual_Income__c</members>
        <members>hed__Affiliation__c.Degree_Type__c</members>
        <members>hed__Affiliation__c.hed__Role__c</members>
        <members>hed__Affiliation__c.hed__Status__c</members>
        <members>hed__Affiliation__c.Transcript_Status__c</members>
        <members>hed__Affiliation__c.Upsert_Key__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>hed__Affiliation__c.Employer</members>
        <members>hed__Affiliation__c.Previous_Institution</members>
        <name>RecordType</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

When I try to run this command:

```
cci task run deploy_pre --org dev
```

I see this error:

> [Failed]: Update of None hed__Affiliation__c.Annual_Income__c: Error:
> An object 'hed__Affiliation__c.Annual_Income__c' of type CustomField
> was
> named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                                                     ... ...                                                               
>
>                                                                                                                                                                    
>                 Update of None hed__Affiliation__c.hed__Status__c: Error: An object 'hed__Affiliation__c.hed__Status__c' of type
> ```
>
> CustomField was named in
> package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
>
> ```
>                 Update of None hed__Affiliation__c.Upsert_Key__c: Error: An object 'hed__Affiliation__c.Upsert_Key__c' of type
> ```
>
> CustomField was named in
> package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
> ... ...
>
> ```
>                 Update of None hed__Affiliation__c.Transcript_Status__c: Error: An object
> ```
>
> 'hed__Affiliation__c.Transcript_Status__c' of type CustomField was
> named
> in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Am I missing anything? If the code is in MDAPI format, then it works fine, but not in SFDX format. Do I need to add some config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove some config. `package.xml` is unnecessary in source format. However, if you wanted or needed it to be compatible in both API modes, I'd suggest that the error you're getting is related to where the `package.xml` is. It appears to be in `unpackaged/pre/eda-customizations/objects`, but it needs to be in `unpackaged/pre/eda-customizations`. By including the file at the wrong location, the API thinks that `hed__Affiliation__c` is the root of the package you're trying to deploy. Try moving it up one directory level and see if that solves your problem.